# SQL Query With UNION Returning One Less Than Expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this query in an attempt to retrieve 4 galleries:

```
(SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
 WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '567' limit 1) 
UNION ALL 
   (SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
    WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '541' limit 1) 
UNION ALL 
   (SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
    WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '484' limit 1) 
UNION ALL 
   (SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
    WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '545' limit 1)
```

However, it returns 3.  If I duplicate the last query, it returns 4.  Any ideas why?

This works but is messy:

```
(SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
 WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '567' limit 1) 
 UNION ALL 
      (SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
       WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '541' limit 1) 
 UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
      WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '484' limit 1) 
 UNION ALL 
     (SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
      WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '545' limit 1) #
 UNION ALL 
      (SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
      WHERE a.pid = b.previewpic and galleryid = '545' limit 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Michael!

Comment: Why not use IN (567, 484, ..., 545) ? and distinct if you have dupes?

Comment: I'm a SQL Novice so I need a bit more explanation of what you mean.

Comment: Also it will be easier if http://sqlfiddle.com/ was set up. or add tag for db vendor/version.

Comment: is the # actually in your query? (between the last 2 unions)

Comment: it is possibly artefact of edit

Comment: There's so many different ways to write this query that would be way more efficient both in terms of query performance and keystrokes.

Comment: Presunably there are matching rows for gallerid 545 but only 2 of the first 3 numbers, so that in the first query you match 3 rows and in the second those rows plus 545's again. Show input (table values) and output.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
edgewe_ngg_pictures p inner join
edgewe_ngg_gallery g on
p.pid = g.previewpic
WHERE  
galleryid in( '567','541','484','545' )
```